# If x == y: print z - Why won't my code print?

Tags: python

I am somewhat new to coding. I am making a quiz where I read in questions from a csv file. I don't understand why my code will not print "Correct. Well Done." when the user inputs a correct answer. Instead, it always prints "Incorrect." I have made sure `userInput` and answer is the same by printing them.

```
FILENAME = 'quiztest.csv'

def welcomeUser():
    name = input("Hello. Please enter your name: ")
    print("Welcome " + name + "!")
    
def readFile():
    with open(FILENAME, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.split(",")
            question = line[0]
            options = line[1]
            answer = line[2]
            askQuestion(question, options, answer)
    
def askQuestion(question, options, answer):
    print(question)
    print(options)
    userInput = input("Please enter the answer: ")
    print(userInput)
    print(answer)
    if userInput == answer:
        print("Correct. Well Done.")
    else:
        print("Incorrect.")
            
    
    
readFile()
```

What is returned:

```
What is my name?
Tom Jeff Fred Sam
Please enter the answer: Sam
Sam
Sam

Incorrect.
```

Comment: @JonathonReinhart No, the newline is **not** included in the string returned by `input`.

Comment: But if the answer is the last part of the line, then it contains one. So, the change should be `answer = line[2].strip()`.

Comment: @CODER123456789, note the [mre] guidelines -- ideally a question should have _the shortest possible program that replicates a specific problem when run without changes_. We don't need your whole quiz program; just something that reads a line from a file and compares a string to it would do. (You could _try_ hardcoding the line from the file and see if that solves the bug, and then _try_ hardcoding the line from user input and see if _that_ solves the bug, and the process of trying those two things would either help you ask a narrow question or give you enough of a hint to solve it yourself).

Comment: @Thierry Err, oops. Thanks, deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the blank line between the last "Sam" and the "Incorrect" in your output.  The value in `answer` includes a newline since it was the last part of the line you read from the input file, and the way you are reading that file, you get a newline at the end of each line that you process.

Your problem is easy to fix. Just call `strip()` to strip the newline off of the end of the input line you read from the input file:

```
def readFile():
    with open(FILENAME, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip().split(",")
            question = line[0]
            options = line[1]
            answer = line[2]
            askQuestion(question, options, answer)
```